# Rolling a weighted number 1-6 in java

Tags: java, random

This project is rolling a 6 sided die and wanting it to land on 6 90% of the time and the other 1-5 2% of the time.

Here is the main class Die

```
public class Die
 {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Instance Variables
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
protected int numSides;
protected Random myRandomNumGenerator;



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Constructors
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/** 
 * Default constructor creates a 6-sided die.
 */
public Die()
{
    numSides = 6;
    myRandomNumGenerator = new Random();
}


/** 
 * This constructor takes in a single integer value and create a die with
 * that number of sides.
 * 
 * @param aNumSides Number of sides to create on the die.
 */
public Die(int aNumSides){
    numSides = aNumSides;
    myRandomNumGenerator = new Random();
}





//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Class Methods
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/** 
 * Getter for the number of sides on the die.
 * 
 * @return The number of sides on the die.
 */
public int getNumOfSides() 
{
    return numSides;
}


/** 
 * Rolls the die to get a random value.
 * 
 * @return A random value between 1 and the number of sides.
 */
public int roll() 
{
    return myRandomNumGenerator.nextInt(numSides) + 1;
}
```

}

and here is the sub class where I need to overide the roll method in die to load the die to the correct value.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LoadedDie extends Die{

protected double loadedPercentage;
protected int numSides;
protected int loadedValue;
protected Random ranNumGenerator; 


public LoadedDie() {
    loadedValue = 6;
    loadedPercentage = .9;



}

public LoadedDie(int aNumSides, int aLoadedValue, double aLoadedPercentage) {
    numSides = aNumSides;
    loadedValue = aLoadedValue;
    loadedPercentage = aLoadedPercentage;




}
public int roll() {

    return ranNumGenerator.nextInt(numSides)+1;




        }



}
```

I have not figured out how to make a random number to come up more often than others.
Thanks

Comment: interesting question use random method not for Generator random no. use as for find the position of odd one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try range between 1 and 50.

Minimum random value, min = 1

Maximum random value, max = 50

```
 int min = 1;
 int max = 50;
 int randomValue = min + (int)(Math.random()*((max-min) + 1));
 int diceValue = (randomValue < 6) ? randomValue : 6;
```

Probability of occurence of each number between 1 and 5: 2%

Probability of occurence of 6: 90%

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement re-worded:

> 6 90% of the time
>
> 5 2%
>
> 4 2%
>
> 3 2%
>
> 2 2%
>
> 1 2%

So map that out to a random number from 1-100 instead of 1-6 and it's pretty simple:

*Disclaimer: I'm not a Java guy, can't verify this works, can be written more efficiently etc, but it gets the point across*

```
int result = ranNumGenerator.nextInt(100);
if(result < 10) return (result % 5) + 1;
return 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

generate a random number between 0 to 9 by using Math.random(). Then just do a check on the result of the random number, if the generated random number is:

0 --> dice is 1/2/3/4/5

1-9 --> dice is 6

Here it will give dice side 6 to show with 90% chance and the rest of the sides with 10% chance. To further give the dice side 1,2,3,4,5 a chance of 2% each you can do the same thing again using the Math.random() and then check it again.

```
int randomNo = (int) Math.random() * 10 //Math.random returns double so need to convert to integer
if(randomNo > 0){
    //dice is 6
}else{
    randomNo = (int) Math.random() * 10
    if(randomNo < 2) //show dice 1
    else if(randomNo < 4) //show dice 2
    else if(randomNo < 6) //show dice 3
    else if(randomNo < 8) //show dice 4
    else if(randomNo < 10) //show dice 5
}
```

Comment: In the `else` clause you could just generate `1 + (int) (5 * Math.Random())` and eliminate the extended if/else sequence.